# What is REGSVR32? Why do we need it?

Tags: windows, dll

I know it is used to "Register or unregister a DLL". But I want more. Why do we need to register a DLL? When should we register a DLL?

Answer (score 21):

It's used when registering COM components (one type of DLL) that various applications require.

By registering a DLL, you are adding information to a central directory (the [Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)) for use by Windows. The information typically includes a "friendly name" for the component, which makes it easier to use from within another program, and the full path to the .dll or .ocx file which actually contains the [executable code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) for the component (this allows Windows to find specific functions in the component which are available for use and to make calls to the executable code). When a software developer designs components to use this registration system this also helps to avoid [software versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning) problems since the information stored in the registry will normally reference the latest version of the component.

It will be very rare that you will need to use this yourself, but one common usage is to unregister and then reregister a DLL if you are experiencing problems or need to install a particular version.

Most of the time an application installer will call this behind this scenes.

> You can use the Regsvr32 tool (Regsvr32.exe) to register and
>   unregister OLE controls such as DLL or ActiveX Controls (OCX) files
>   that are self-registerable. This may be necessary to troubleshoot some
>   issues with Windows, Microsoft Internet Explorer, or other programs.

Source: [Explanation of Regsvr32 usage and error messages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873)

Comment: You often have to do it in Wine.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, its just like chrisF said, [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873) is a KB article from microsoft explaining it as well and [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815065) is a KB article explaining what a DLL is. Think of them as library files for programs on your computer. They hold instructions on how to do different things for different programs. When you register it you are telling your computer that you have these instructions, where there at and programs that say they need them can use them now.

Comment: I still don't understand why the frig one would need to REGISTER a DLL. Why is it not enough to just dump it in the same directory in which the executable that needs it resides? Or just make it accessible by adding the path of the containing directory to the PATH environment variable?`

Comment: @antred if you have a new question then please use the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Re-registering dll's is common to do when fixing many Windows issues including repairing Windows Update when it stops working, see method 2, also see some of the links in "More Information" section

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943144